# If $\|a-b\| < \|b\|$ what follows for $\|a\|$?

Tags: vectors, normed-spaces

Let
$$
 \|a-b\| < \|b\| 
$$
where $a, b \in C^n$.
Аre they following any relations for $\|a\|$ or $\|b\|$?

($\|.\|$ is the 2-norm of vectors)

Answer (score 6):

That says geometrically that $a$ is inside the ball of radius $\|b\|$ with center $b$ .

Comment: Ethan. Was just about to write something quite similar:)

Answer (score 5):

It follows that $a$ cannot be the null vector and that therefore $\lVert a\rVert\neq0$. And it also follows that$$\lVert a\rVert=\lVert a-b+b\rVert\leqslant\lVert a-b\rVert+\lVert b\rVert<2\lVert b\rVert.$$